# Java 11: New HTTP client send POST requests with x-www-form-urlencoded parameters

Tags: java, java-http-client

I'm trying to send a POST request using the new http client api.
Is there a built in way to send parameters formatted as `x-www-form-urlencoded` ?

My current code:

```
HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
        .uri(URI.create(url))
        .header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
        .POST(BodyPublishers.ofString("a=get_account&account=" + URLEncoder.encode(account, "UTF-8")))
        .build();
```

What I'm looking is for a better way to pass the parameters. Something like this:

```
Params p=new Params();
p.add("a","get_account");
p.add("account",account);
```

Do I need to build myself this functionality or is something already built in?

I'm using Java 12.

Comment: Frustratingly, you need to do it yourself.  There’s been [an open bug for it](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6306820) since Java 6.

Comment: as described here: https://golb.hplar.ch/2019/01/java-11-http-client.html#formdata-x-www-form-urlencoded you can build your own BodyPublisher which takes a Map interface as input

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I think the following is the best way to achieve this using Java 11:

```java
Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<>();
parameters.put("a", "get_account");
parameters.put("account", account);

String form = parameters.entrySet()
    .stream()
    .map(e -> e.getKey() + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(e.getValue(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
    .collect(Collectors.joining("&"));

HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();

HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
    .uri(URI.create(url))
    .header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    .POST(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString(form))
    .build();

HttpResponse<?> response = client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());

System.out.println(response.statusCode() + " " + response.body().toString());
```

Comment: I'm getting a "The method ofString(String) from the type HttpRequest.BodyPublishers refers to the missing type HttpRequest$BodyPublisher" error. Couldn't find a solution over the internet. Do you know why this might happend?

Comment: you need to encode the parameter's names `URLEncoder.encode(e.getKey(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)`

Answer (score 4):

This way could be useful:

```
String param = Map.of("param1", "value1", "param2", "value2")
      .entrySet()
      .stream()
      .map(entry -> Stream.of(
               URLEncoder.encode(entry.getKey(), UTF_8),
               URLEncoder.encode(entry.getValue(), UTF_8))
                .collect(Collectors.joining("="))
      ).collect(Collectors.joining("&"));
```

You can use up to 10 pairs (param, value) by `Map.of(...)`. It returns an unmodifiable map.

Answer (score 4):

As Łukasz Olszewski  said , worked correctly :

```
String params = Map.of(
                    Constants.PARAM_CLIENT_ID, apiObject.getClientId(),
                    Constants.PARAM_SCOPE, apiObject.getScope(),
                    Constants.PARAM_CODE, apiObject.getCode(),
                    Constants.PARAM_REDIRECT_URI, apiObject.getRedirectUri(),
                    Constants.PARAM_GRANT_TYPE, apiObject.getGrantType(),
                    Constants.PARAM_CODE_VERIFIER, apiObject.getCodeVerifier())
                    .entrySet()
                    .stream()
                    .map(entry -> Stream.of(
                            URLEncoder.encode(entry.getKey(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8),
                            URLEncoder.encode(entry.getValue(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
                            .collect(Collectors.joining("="))
                    ).collect(Collectors.joining("&"));

HttpResponse<?> response = utils.consumeHttpPostFormUrlEncodedClientByRequestUrl(Constants.URL_BASE + Constants.URL_GET_TOKEN, params);
```

and consumeHttpPostFormUrlEncodedClientByRequestUrl

```
public HttpResponse<?> consumeHttpPostFormUrlEncodedClientByRequestUrl(String url, String map) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
        HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder(URI.create(url))
                .header("Content-Type", String.valueOf(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED))
                .POST(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString(map))
                .build();
        return httpClient.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of Stream.of you can use more compact String.join (according to Łukasz Olszewski answer):

```
String form = Map.of("param1", "value1", "param2", "value2")
  .entrySet()
  .stream()
  .map(entry -> String.join("=",
                        URLEncoder.encode(entry.getKey().toString(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8),
                        URLEncoder.encode(entry.getValue().toString(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)))
                .collect(Collectors.joining("&"));
return HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString(form);
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Methanol](https://mizosoft.github.io/methanol/). It's got a nice [`FormBodyPublisher`](https://mizosoft.github.io/methanol/multipart_and_forms/#form-bodies) for `x-www-form-urlencoded` bodies.

```java
var formBody = FormBodyPublisher.newBuilder()
      .query("a", "get_account")
      .query("account", account)
      .build();
var request = MutableRequest.POST("https://example.com", formBody);

// Methanol implements an HttpClient that does nice things to your request/response.
// Here, the Content-Type header will be added for you.
var client = Methanol.create();
var response = client.send(request, BodyHandlers.ofString());
```

Comment: Why is it using var? :o

Answer (score 0):

Here is a helper method for converting a `Map` into a URL encoded form-data payload:

```java
private static String getFormDataAsString(Map<String, String> formData) {
    var formBodyBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> singleEntry : formData.entrySet()) {
        if (formBodyBuilder.length() > 0) {
            formBodyBuilder.append("&");
        }
        formBodyBuilder.append(URLEncoder.encode(singleEntry.getKey(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        formBodyBuilder.append("=");
        formBodyBuilder.append(URLEncoder.encode(singleEntry.getValue(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    }
    return formBodyBuilder.toString();
}
```

You can easily use it like so:

```java
var formData = Map.of(
    "key-1", "value-1",
    "key-2", "value-2",
    "key-3", "value-3"
);

var request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
        .uri(requestUri)
        .header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
        .POST(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString(getFormDataAsString(formData)))
        .build();
```

Additional gotchas:

- Make sure to use `POST` or `PUT` as the HTTP method verb, because most servers will ignore the body on `GET` requests.
- If you're sending HTML with CSS and/or JS in the request body, make sure to encode it in Base64 format, because many proxies and firewalls will reject your request due to potentially dangerous links or scripts in the payload.